# Returnable but not queryable fields in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to store an array in an elasticsearch document that is of variable length. Ideally, this array could then be merged when queried with an aggregation. Any queried array will be of equal length because of business logic but there will be different length arrays in the index. Here are two example documents:

```
{
  "array": [1, 2, 3, 4],
  "test1": "testing123",
  "test2": "testing_another"
}
{
  "array": [4, 3, 2, 1],
  "test1": "testing123",
  "test2": "testing_another"
}
```

And with an aggregation I'd like to get a result that contained

```
{
  "array": [5, 5, 5, 5]
}
```

The only way I've thought to do this would be to store the arrays as a hash whose values could then be summed in the aggregation:

```
{
  "array": {"0": 4, "1": 3, "2": 2, "3": 1}
}
{
  "array": {"0": 1, "1": 2, "2": 3, "3": 4}
}
```

So that the aggregated result looks like (using sum on "0", "1", "2", "3" fields)

```
{
  "array": {"0": 5, "1": 5, "2": 5, "3": 5}
}
```

But it seems that as the hash size increases elasticsearch slows down on writes, probably due to that fact that is indexing these fields thinking that I might query on them. This is not necessary, I only need to be able to get the merged (summed) result on the way out.

Is this a reasonable assessment of the situation? If so, is there a way in elasticsearch to specify that a given field will not need to be queried on?

Answer (score 1):

@cmwright it sounds a bit weird to ask for something that was built mainly for search to do not allow a field to be searchable :) nevertheless, what you can certainly do is to define a field in your index to do not be analyzed through a mapping. More info here [Elastic Search Mapping Core Types](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html). I dont give you a direct answer to your question but I hope that at least you can get some clues to figure out a possible solution.

Comment: I understand the predicament that's being presented here. I want to be able to return data based on a search, so still using the software as expected. I just don't need to search on *all* fields in the document

Comment: Also @cpard, it looks like the "index" field is only applicable to how the database parses strings/text. Is there another field that I've skipped?

Comment: @cmwright I'm terrible sorry because I interpreted completely wrong what you said about storing the arrays as hashes. The aggregation functions that ES has allow the usage of the scripting module, have a look at [link](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html) and this [link](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html). To be honest I do not have a concrete answer right now but I would see if I can combine the Sum function with some scripting.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify your array to be not analyzed for search with the help of mapping

```
{
    "array": { 
        "type":     "string",
        "index":    "not_analyzed"
    }
}
```

where `array` being your field name. You can read more on elasticsearch refrence for mappings at [Mappings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html)

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure if the size of the hash is what caused the issue, but I found two field mapping parameters in the elasticsearch 6.2 docs that allow you to specify that a field should not be queried on.

- Use index=False to disable indexing for that specific field. Fields that are not indexed are not queryable.
- Use enabled=False to disable indexing (and ALL processing) for that field and all of its children (Only applicable to object fields)

Sources:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/mapping-index.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/enabled.html